# Angular JS: ng-repeat in Marquee

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, marquee

how to use marquee with ng-repeat in angular js?

I tried

```
<marquee>
        <span ng-repeat="item in allItems">
          <img src="img/ticker.png" style="padding-top:3px;">{{item.news}}
          </span> 
</marquee>
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Also, please suggest some sliding news ticker designed in Angular Way.

Comment: wasn't marquee deprecated ?

Comment: As @svarog said, have a look at this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee. Actually, you should do it with css3 rules.

Comment: And I found this fiddle to replace your marquee : http://jsfiddle.net/MaY5A/1/

Answer (score 3):

you have forgotten the `{{ }}` marks

```
<marquee>
      <span ng-repeat="item in allItems">
          <img src="img/ticker.png" style="padding-top:3px;">{{item.news}}
      </span> 
</marquee>
```

**EDIT:** since you have edited your question to include the solution

marquee is deprecated in HTML5, you should use a CSS solution, or an angular one
here is a [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thenetfreaker/qt0rmahr/2/) with marquee functionality, and [a ticker](http://codepen.io/ajf-/pen/eCjHG)

Comment: sorry folks. I made a copy paste error.. the problem is ng repeat somehow doesn't work with span tags

Comment: I have already used the angular directive., but it has jquery and jquery marquee as requirements. which I am trying to avoid. but thanks for efforts

Comment: i've changed the link to an angular marquee

Answer (score 1):

### There is a working example on jsfiddle.

```
<div ng-app="TestAPP">
    <div ng-controller='test'>
<marquee >
      <span ng-repeat="item in allItems">
          <img src="img/ticker.png" style="paddingtop:3px;"/>            
          {{item.news}}
      </span> 
</marquee> 
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rod3qo7x/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```js
 angular.module('angular-news-ticker', [])
 .controller('newsCtrl', function ($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.start=0;
  $scope.totalitem=4;
  $scope.news=[{obj:'news1'},{obj:'news2'},{obj:'news3'},{obj:'news4'},{obj:'news5'},{obj:'news6'},{obj:'news1'},{obj:'news2'},{obj:'news3'},{obj:'news4'},{obj:'news5'},{obj:'news6'}];
  $scope.totalnumofitem=$scope.news.length;
  $scope.next=function () {
   if ($scope.totalitem < $scope.totalnumofitem) {
    $scope.start += 1;
    $scope.totalitem +=1;
   }else{
    $scope.start=0;
    $scope.totalitem=4;
   }
  }
  $scope.prev=function () {
   if ($scope.start>0) {
    $scope.start -= 1;
    $scope.totalitem -=1;
   }
  }
  $interval(moveat, 500);
  function moveat() {
     if ($scope.totalitem < $scope.totalnumofitem) {
    $scope.start += 1;
    $scope.totalitem +=1;
   }else{
    $scope.start=0;
    $scope.totalitem=4;
   }
 }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="angular-news-ticker">
<head>
 <title>demo page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body ng-controller="newsCtrl">
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading">
  <span>news</span>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="new in news.slice(start, totalitem)" >{{new.obj}}</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="panel-footer">
  <ul class="pagination pull-right">
      <li><a href="#" class="prev" ng-click="prev()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="next" ng-click="next()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```